How to Make Background Image Responsive with CSS?
I'm working on an FAQ section for my webpage, but I'm having trouble making its background responsive. It isn't adjusting well on different screen sizes.


html {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url('https://wallpapers.com/images/featured/1920-x-1080-night-city-y13hx1qucv0ztepv.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  min-height: 40%;
  max-width: 60%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3%;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
}

.question {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  padding: 0 0 15px 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.question::after {
  content: "+";
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
}

.answer {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}

.question-container.active .answer {
  height: 40px;
}

.question-container.active .question {
  font-size: 1rem;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}

.question-container .active .question::after {
  content: "-";
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}
<div class="container">
  <h2>Frequently Asked Questions</h2>
  <div class="question-container">
    <p class="question">What is the return policy?</p>
    <p class="answer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam porro quidem eum praesentium officia voluptas repellendus amet minima alias voluptates beatae ea non, natus numquam sint, nam quasi aspernatur aliquam.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="question-container">
    <p class="question">When will I receive my order?</p>
    <p class="answer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam porro quidem eum praesentium officia voluptas repellendus amet minima alias voluptates beatae ea non, natus numquam sint, nam quasi aspernatur aliquam.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="question-container">
    <p class="question">Where are you located?</p>
    <p class="answer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam porro quidem eum praesentium officia voluptas repellendus amet minima alias voluptates beatae ea non, natus numquam sint, nam quasi aspernatur aliquam.</p>
  </div>
</div>



Issue:
The FAQ sections background isn't responsive.

I've tried using max-width, min-height, and percentages, but the
layout still doesn't adjust properly on different screen sizes.
The content either overflows or looks too cramped on smaller screens.

What I've Tried:

Using max-width and min-height for the container.

Setting width and height as percentages.

Adding media queries to adjust styles for different screen sizes.


Desired Outcome:
I want the FAQ section to be fully responsive, adjusting smoothly across various screen sizes, without overflow or cramped content.
Can anyone help me figure out why my UI's background is not responsive and suggest improvements?
Below are the screenshots of how they look at different screen size i.e 1440px,1024px,425px respectively




Looks absolutely fine on all screen sizes for me. Maybe add a screenshot of what you're seeing that you don't like.

The title of your post indicates the problem is with the background image, but the last couple of paragraphs of your post indicate a problem with the content. The code snippet doesn’t demonstrate a problem with either of these. Please (a) confirm that the snippet does indeed demonstrate the problem, and (b) edit your post to clarify exactly what you are unhappy with.

@BrettDonald I have edited my concern which is based on background and thank you for rectifying my error

Thanks, @Exploring_lee, but I still don’t see a problem with the background – to me it looks totally fine on both narrow and wide screens. You’ll need to edit your post again to include some screenshots and mockups to make it clear to us what you expect/want to happen versus what actually happens.

@ralph.m I have uploaded the screenshot of how they look at different screen size

@BrettDonald I have edited the question by uploading screenshot,while they should take up whole up screen properly but they aren't

Have you got a viewport meta tag? Because SO includes it by default in snippets so it would be fixed here. Something like <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> Otherwise: cannot replicate.

@somethinghere Thank you,it did work for my code and solving the issue

It looks like you are missing a viewport meta tag, something like:
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

This is just an example (user-scalable=no will probably get ignored due to accessibility concerns). The reason your snippet didn't have this behaviour is that Stack Overflow adds the meta tag itself to the snippet pages to keep their scaling consistent.
